# Wpf - Template property is null in constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, datatemplate

After the class is initialized, template property returns the correct value but in constructor it always returns null. I tried to call `ApplyTemplate()` method in constructor but it didn't work.
Can anyone explain how and why that happens?
Is it possible to get template property in constructor correctly?
Thanks in advance!

**Style**

```
 <Style x:Key="DesignerItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dataModel:Component}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <converter:ComponentHeightConverter x:Key="componentHeightConverter"/>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type dataModel:Component}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">

                        <Grid x:Name="PART_MainGrid">

                            <!-- PART_ContentPresenter -->
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ContentPresenter"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Padding}"
                                          Cursor="Arrow"/>

                            <!-- PART_ResizeDecorator -->
                            <Control x:Name="PART_ResizeDecorator" 
                                 Visibility="Collapsed"
                                 Template="{StaticResource ResizeDecoratorTemplate}"/>

                            <!-- PART_DragThumb -->
                            <c:DragThumb x:Name="PART_DragThumb"
                                     Template="{StaticResource MoveThumbTemplate}"
                                     ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"
                                     Cursor="SizeAll"/>

                            <c:RelativePositionPanel x:Name="PART_ConnectorNames" 
                                                     Visibility="{Binding Path=(viewModel:ToolbarViewModel.IsPortLabelVisible), 
                                                                  Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>

                            <!-- PART_ConnectorDecorator -->
                            <Control x:Name="PART_ConnectorDecorator"
                                 Visibility="Visible" Panel.ZIndex="1000"
                                 Template="{StaticResource ConnectorDecoratorTemplate}"/>

                        </Grid>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="PART_NameBlock"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding Path=(viewModel:ToolbarViewModel.IsComponentLabelVisible), Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding DisplayedName}" Grid.Row="1">
                            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform X="5" Y="5"/>
                            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Value="True" Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=IsSelected}"/>
                                <Condition Value="{x:Static sys:Guid.Empty}" Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=ParentID}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_ResizeDecorator" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_ConnectorDecorator" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_DragThumb" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_DragThumb" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=IsDragConnectionOver}">
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_ConnectorDecorator" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
```

**Concrete Class**

```
   public Component() 
    { 
        var template = this.Template; //Here template property returns null
    }
```

Comment: Can you post any relevant code that could make your problem easier to understand?

Comment: Insert your code to the question

Comment: I edited the question. Hope now it's clear

Comment: I think the problem may rise because of the style is not applied to the actual control. Try to manually set the style to the control using its key.

Answer (score 3):

You can call **UpdateDefaultStyle()** method before accessing **Template** property.
e.g.:

```
var button= new Button();
button.UpdateDefaultStyle();
button.Template // template is not null here
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override OnApplyTemplate method and access template inside this method.

```
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        var template = Template; // template is not null here
    }
```